# QGraphicsGridLayout works in PySide but not PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qgraphicsview

I've been trying for hours to get `QGraphicsGridLayout` to work with `PyQt4`. I have `PySide` installed so I switched the imports to that for a quick check and it worked as expected! For the code below, when `PySide` is used, the `paint` method on the `RectangleWidget` is called as expected but when you use `PyQt4` the `paint` method is never called.

I know that the `RectangleWidget` should override some more virtual methods for a proper implementation but I was stripping things out to try and get the minimal amount of code to narrow down the problem.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
# from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class RectangleWidget(QtGui.QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(self, rect, parent=None):
        super(RectangleWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rect = rect

    def paint(self, painter, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Paint Called')
        painter.drawRect(self.rect)


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        central_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(central_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        panel = QtGui.QGraphicsWidget()
        self.scene.addItem(panel)

        layout = QtGui.QGraphicsGridLayout()
        panel.setLayout(layout)

        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                rectangle = RectangleWidget(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 50, 50))
                layout.addItem(rectangle, i, j)

        central_layout.addWidget(self.view)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Any help is appreciated! I would like to maintain compatibility with both `PyQt4` and `PySide` so continuing using `PySide` only is not really an ideal solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QGraphicsGridLayout` takes ownership of the items added to it (see the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsgridlayout.html#details) for further details).

In your example, it would seem that all the `RectangleWidget` items are in danger of being garbage-collected once they go out of scope. So if you give them a parent:

```
    rectangle = RectangleWidget(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 50, 50), panel)
```

all should be well.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this only happened with the GridLayout in PyQt4? LinearLayout worked fine in both PyQt4 and PySide. I've been generally ignoring the ownership aspect for now but I guess it's time I stop overlooking it. Thanks.

Comment: @D2B. Hard to say: garbage-collection can be unpredictable. And that is why ignoring ownership can be risky.